Distribution of $Z$ = min($y_1, y_2, ... y_n$) $-$ max($x_1, x_2, ... x_n$)
Given two samples $x_1, x_2, ... x_n$ and $y_1, y_2, ... y_n$, whose values are in [0, 1], what is the distribution of $Z$ = min({$y_1, y_2, ... y_n$}) $-$ max($x_1, x_2, ... x_n$)? It is usually the the case that $Y >= X$, but this doesn't always occur.
To me, this seems very similar to the distribution of the range, $R$ = max($x_1, x_2, ... x_n$) $-$ min($x_1, x_2, ... x_n$), with a few obvious changes: two random variables instead of one, as well as a positivity constraint. Thus, one needs to consider the joint distribution between the two samples and evaluate a double integral.
As context, the $x$s snd $y$s represent pairwise genetic distances among sample specimens. Likely though, these are not IID.

Your setup doesn't involve any samples but your question does; maybe worth elaborating on that.

Thanks - fixed. It should be clearer now.

-1 What exactly do you mean by $\min(Y)$?  The minimum $\min(Y)$ of a single random variable $Y$ would usually just be the random variable $Y$ itself, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_an_absolutely_continuous_distribution so I'm not able to make much sense of your question.

... and are you conditioning on $Y\ge X$ or assuming it is always the case that $Y\ge X$?

Thanks all. Hopefully I have clarified things enough to reopen the question. Otherwise, please let me know where further explanation is needed.

Because the question is about computing a probability, the reference at the end to nonparametric bootstrapping is jarring: what does one have to do with the other? There's nothing one can say in the generality with which this has been posed because you don't assume anything about the distributions (other than about their supports). The solution is elementary for independent data (appearing here on CV numerous times) and otherwise cannot be simplified.

If you intend that the Y's and X's are independent within each set of variables and / or across them, please state that explicitly in the question.

Please let me know if I understood correctly the question.
Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables with absolutely continuous marginal distributions, support on $[0,1]$ and marginal CDFs $F_X$ and $F_Y$, respectively. Let $\{(X_j,Y_j)\}_{j=1}^{n}$ be an i.i.d sample of size $n$ from the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$.
Then, the order statistics $X_{(n)}:=\max\{X_j\}_{j=1}^{n}$ and $Y_{(1)}:=\min\{Y_j\}_{j=1}^{n}$, have marginal CDFs:
$$
\begin{aligned}
F_{X_{(n)}}(x) &= [F_X(x)]^{n},\\
F_{Y_{(1)}}(y) &= 1-[1-F_Y(y)]^{n}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Under the joint constraint $X\leq Y$ almost surely, one has two independent chains $X_{(1)}\leq X_j\leq X_{(n)}\leq Y_{(n)}$ and $X_{(1)}\leq Y_{(1)}\leq Y_j\leq Y_{(n)}$, for all $j\in\{1,...,n\}$. Notice these chains do not link $X_{(n)}$ and $Y_{(1)}$. In other words, neither one constraints the other, i.e., they are independent. Then, the CDF of $Z=Y_{(1)}-X_{(n)}$ can be derived via simple convolution (using $Y_{(1)}=Z+X_{(n)}$):
$$
\begin{aligned}
F_Z(z) &= \int_0^1 F_{Y_{(1)}}(z+x)\,\text{d}F_{X_{(n)}}(x),\\
&= n\int_0^1 \left[1-[1-F_Y(z+x)]^{n}\right]\,\left[F_X(x)\right]^{n-1}\,\text{d}F_{X}(x).\\
\end{aligned}
$$
The support of $Z$ is $[-1,1]$.

Since the result involves a convolution $Y = X + Z$, maybe mention this for other readers?
